# How to re-synchronise all Active directory with Alfresco share

Tags: active-directory, ldap, alfresco, alfresco-share

my LDAP synchronisation of alfresco is already done, but some entries are missing
then i added new attributes to LDAP synchronisation of alfresco,
but the changes are operated only when someone changes something in the Active Directory

i want to apply the synchronisation for all users form alfresco without changing something in the AD.

This is my `alfresco-global.properties` file:

```
    ###############################
    ## Common Alfresco Properties #
    ###############################

    dir.root=C:/Alfresco/alf_data

    alfresco.context=alfresco
    alfresco.host=127.0.0.1
    alfresco.port=8080
    alfresco.protocol=http

    share.context=share
    share.host=127.0.0.1
    share.port=8080
    share.protocol=http

    ### database connection properties ###
    db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
    db.username=alfresco
    db.password=admin
    db.name=alfresco
    db.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/${db.name}

    #--------------------------------------------->  debut modif 


    ### E-mail site invitation setting ###
    notification.email.siteinvite=true
    mail.host=test2015.test.be
    mail.port=25
    ###mail.encoding=UTF-8
    mail.from.default=alfresco@test.be
    mail.from.enabled=true
    ###mail.protocol=smtp
    mail.username=alfresco@test.be
    mail.password=testone
    ###activities.feed.notifier.enabled=false

    authentication.chain==ldap-ad1:ldap-ad,alfrescoNtlm1:alfrescoNtlm

    ### LDAP Integration ###
    synchronization.import.cron=0 0/10 9-18 ? * MON-FRI
    synchronization.allowDeletions=true
    synchronization.syncOnStartup=true
    synchronization.synchronizeChangesOnly=false
    synchronization.syncWhenMissingPeopleLogIn=true
    synchronization.authCreatePeopleOnLogin=true
    ldap.synchronization.active=true
    ldap.authentication.java.naming.provider.url=ldap://C2SRVDC1.test.be:389
    ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.principal=alfresco@test.be
    ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.credentials=Henry
    ldap.synchronization.groupSearchBase=ou\=Institut erasme,dc\=erasme,dc=be
    ldap.synchronization.userSearchBase=ou\=Institut erasme,dc=\erasme,dc=be


    ldap.authentication.active=true
    ldap.authentication.userNameFormat=%s@erasme.be
    ldap.authentication.java.naming.security.authentication=simple

    ################# ATTRIBUTE MAPPING #############
    #### mapping to unique username in username attribute### 
    #ldap.synchronization.userLastNameAttributeName=cn
    #ldap.synchronization.userEmailAttributeName=mail
    #ldap.synchronization.userFirstNameAttributeName=givenName
    ldap.synchronization.groupIdAttributeName=cn
    #ldap.synchronization.groupType=
    #ldap.synchronization.personType=
    ldap.synchronization.groupMemberAttributeName=member
    #ldap.synchronization.userOrganizationalIdAttributeName=company

    ##-------------------------FIN DE LA MODIFICATION

    ### FTP Server Configuration ###
    ftp.enabled=true
    ftp.port=21

    ### RMI service ports ###
    alfresco.rmi.services.port=50500
    avm.rmi.service.port=0
    avmsync.rmi.service.port=0
    attribute.rmi.service.port=0
    authentication.rmi.service.port=0
    repo.rmi.service.port=0
    action.rmi.service.port=0
    deployment.rmi.service.port=0

    ### External executable locations ###
    ooo.exe=C:/Alfresco/libreoffice/App/libreoffice/program/soffice.exe
    ooo.enabled=true
    ooo.port=8100
    img.root=C:\\Alfresco\\imagemagick
    img.coders=${img.root}\\modules\\coders
    img.config=${img.root}\\config
    img.gslib=${img.root}\\lib
    img.exe=${img.root}\\convert.exe
    swf.exe=C:/Alfresco/swftools/pdf2swf.exe
    swf.languagedir=C:/Alfresco/swftools/japanese

    jodconverter.enabled=false
    jodconverter.officeHome=C:/Alfresco/libreoffice/App/libreoffice
    jodconverter.portNumbers=8100

    ### Initial admin password ###
    alfresco_user_store.adminpassword=209c6174da490caeb422f3fa5a7ae634

    ### E-mail site invitation setting ###
    notification.email.siteinvite=false

    ### License location ###
    dir.license.external=C:/Alfresco

    ### Solr indexing ###
    index.subsystem.name=solr
    dir.keystore=${dir.root}/keystore
    solr.port.ssl=8443

    ### BPM Engine ###
    system.workflow.engine.jbpm.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the [Alfresco docs on Triggering a full ldap sync](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/The_Synchronization_Subsystem#Triggering_a_full_ldap_sync), to force a full resync at server startup, add to your alfresco global properties

```
synchronization.synchronizeChangesOnly=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is ok but you must take into account that in Community edition full sync never happens on startup, only incremental syncs happen at startup. Full sync can only happen via the scheduled sync job.

See [Alfresco forums: How to force a Full Sync](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/installation-upgrades-configuration-integration/authentication-ldap-sso/how-force-full-sync)